Ubuntu 24.10: Log in via remote login with a user account
I'm a bit confused about the design of this feature. How can I use the user's credentials to authenticate RDP directly, instead of the separate credentials set in the configuration? I don't understand why there's an extra layer. I want RDP to go straight to the desktop after logging in, without requiring the user's credentials again at the lock screen.
